# How to make javac find JAR files? (Eclipse can see them)

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

When I'm in Eclipse my project compiles with no errors, however when I try to compile with `javac` it says I'm missing some packages...

I copied my compile command and some of the error text below:

```
javac -classpath lib/ -d bin/ src/*.java
src/Cleaner.java:5: package net.sourceforge.jgeocoder does not exist
src/MyUtilities.java:19: package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist
```

In Eclipse, I have added all the .JAR files to the build-path, and the program compiles just fine.

Why can it not find the jars when I use javac instead of the Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Because Eclipse was *told* where to look but javac wasn't :-) There is no magic here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`-classpath lib/` will cause `javac` to look for a tree of class files in `lib`. If you have JAR archives there, you have to use `-classpath lib/*.jar` - and probably use whatever escaping mechanism your CLI has on the * to make sure it reaches `javac` rather than being expanded by the CLI

See the [javac command reference (windows)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

Answer (score 20):

Existing answer, as informative as it is, still left me wondering, having to go over the javac -classpath docs. Here's a revision of what you might want to know:

`javac -cp "lib/" Example.java` will load all `.class` files in `lib/`.
`javac -cp "lib/\*" Example.java` will load all `.jar` files in `lib/`, but not the `.class` files.
`javac -cp "lib/;lib/\*" Example.java` will load all `.jar` and `.class` files in `lib/`.

Notes:

- The `*` (wildcard) character as used in above examples is escaped (note the `\` before `*`). `\` is for bash, if you're using something else it might be different. You want to escape it because the java sdk utilities, like `javac`, their own way of interpreting the wildcard. As far as I can tell (correct me if I'm wrong), Windows command line doesn't expand `*` so you don't need to escape it: `-cp lib\*` should be fine.
- `;` separates paths, as in `javac -cp ".;a/;b/;c/" Example.java` – this would load `.class` files in the following directories: current directory, a, b and c.
- Surround the classpath with quotes (like in examples) when using separators (`;`).

Comment: Nice clarification. I would add to it that the "add quotes" and "use ; to separate" is windows specific. In linux you should use a colon ":" instead of a semicolon, and quotes are not necessary but may be required if there are spaces in your filenames. Finally, it's worth pointing out (as I found out the hard way) that the "/*" syntax only works when using it from the commandline. It will not work from an @argfile; you have to specify all .jar files individually in that.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the existing answers to clarify the case when using [@argfiles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#commandlineargfile).

Assume you have the following project structure:

```
MyProject
├── lib
│   ├── lib1.jar
│   ├── lib2.jar
│   └── speciallib
│       ├── speciallib1.jar
│       └── speciallib2.jar
├── out
└── src
    └── MyClass.java
```

If you were to compile this on the command line (e.g. using linux path separators), you can say

```
javac -d out -sourcepath src -classpath 'lib/*:lib/speciallib/*' src/MyClass.java
```

However, if you wanted to create an @argfile to keep things tidy, then the '*' syntax will not work. You'll need to specify all .jar files in your classpath individually. So the @argfile for this would look like this:

```
-d out

-sourcepath src

-classpath '\
lib/lib1.jar:\
lib/lib2.jar:\
lib/speciallib/speciallib1.jar:\
lib/speciallib/speciallib2.jar\
'

src/MyClass.java
```

which you would then run like this:

```
javac @argfile
```

Thankfully, it is not too difficult to dump all .jar files into your file in an automated manner. E.g. an easy way on linux is to use the find command (also passing to sed to append a colon path separator and a backslash for line continuation) and append this to your argfile. E.g.

```
find lib -name "*.jar" | sed "s/\$/:\\\\/" >> argfile
```