# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONObject - java commandline runtime error

Tags: java, command-line, json, runtimeexception

I'm trying to create a JSON object in java and compile it.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
class JsonEncodeDemo 
{

   public static void main(String[] args){

  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

  obj.put("name", "foo");
  obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
  obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
  obj.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));

  System.out.print(obj);
   }
}
```

I have downloaded json-simple-1.1.1.jar and its present in my current folder. 
I compile using

```
javac -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar JsonEncodeDemo.java.
```

It compiles fine. But when I try to run it -

```
java JsonEncodeDemo
```

It gives me the following -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONObject
   at JsonEncodeDemo.main(JsonEncodeDemo.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONObject
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I have also put the jar in my lib and bin folders and tried compiling with -

```
javac -cp '.\bin\*;.\lib\*;json-simple-1.1.1.jar' JsonEncodeDemo.java
```

and running

```
java JsonEncodeDemo
```

It still doesn't work. Can someone help me out here please?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError means that class or one of its dependencies is not present. So look at what dependencies it has

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, json-simple-1.1.1.jar is in the same dir as JsonEncodeDemo:

compile

```
javac -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar JsonEncodeDemo.java
```

run

```
java -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar: JsonEncodeDemo
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390904/3914072 - also javac -cp "./;./\*" Example.java will load all .jar and .class files in current directory and java -cp "./;./\*" Example.java will properly run them. Worked for me.