# classpath issues outside of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a very simple piece of code I am trying to run on the Windows command line (Windows 7). It runs in Eclipse fine.

I have read [How to make javac find JAR files? (Eclipse can see them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182465/how-to-make-javac-find-jar-files-eclipse-can-see-them)

and

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html#Understanding

but clearly am missing something or misunderstanding something.

Here's the code:

```
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreUtil;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.Notifier;
public class MakeUniqIDs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.println(EcoreUtil.generateUUID());
        }
    }

}
```

When I try to compile it with javac I get following error message: "MakeUniqIDs.java:1: error: package org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util does not exist"

I am in the src directory where the above code lives, and used the following to attempt to compile it:
javac -classpath "..\lib\org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.13.0v28170609-0707.jar" MakeUniqIDs.java

I put the jar files in the lib directory, and also tried putting the path to the eclipse plugins directory into the classpath, but still no go.

Comment: if you use -classpath parameter you have to list all needed jar files, not their directories. If you use relative path like ..\lib it must be relative to the current directory from where you ran your command. JAR file content is a root to find classes not directory where jar file is.

Comment: the classpath above is, I think, to the jar file, which I put in the lib directory.  the ..\lib is relative to where I ran the command. So I'm still not sure what I'm missing.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: "I think, to the jar file, which I put in the lib directory" you have to have that jar file(s) in the -classpath as well, not just lib directory

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify external JAR on the classpath.

```
java -cp path/some.jar; etc.
```

You are using classes that are part of Eclipse itself. You could dig out their JAR, but that's generally not a good idea. generateUUID() seems to be used to create a UUID in source file based on the file content, which is an IDE feature.

Comment: @Vasan You're right, but -cp is part of javac as well.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that the jar is in that path, and the name is exactly the same `ls ..\lib` or `dir ..\lib`. Then use the command (with the right path):

```
javac -classpath "..\lib\org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.13.0v28170609-0707.jar" MakeUniqIDs.java
```

Also note that you have imported `org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.Notifier;`, and that class is in the jar `org.eclipse.emf.common` not `ecore`, you can remove the line (since you are not using it) or add the jar separated with `;`.

Example:

```
javac -classpath "..\lib\org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.13.0v28170609-0707.jar;..\lib\org.eclipse.emf.common_2.13.0v28170609-0707.jar" MakeUniqIDs.java
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I mistyped the first .jar filename--thanks for suggesting the dir/ls!

Comment: @BrianNolan you're welcome, that happens. Try to use `tab` when you can.